# accessing google adwords bucket using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api, google-play-console, gsutil

I am able to access the play console buckets through gsutil scripts.
Now I want to access the adwords (uses same gmail account) but there is no clear documentation for that. There are hints that it may be paid as well.
Has anyone done that?  What are the steps and is it free or paid.

Answer (score 0):

[Data transfer for Google Ads/Adwords](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer) does not export data to Cloud Strorage buckets as for the [Google Play data transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/play-transfer). The target must be a BigQuery dataset instead.

The transfer functionality itself is free, but normal data storage and querying pricing applies once the data is in BiqQuery.